# Как поступать с сообщениями, содержащими плагиат (нарушающими лицензию на содержимое)?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, авторские-права

В целях данного вопроса под плагиатом предлагаю понимать следующее:

> Плагиат — это любое заимствование, при котором полностью или частично не выполняются условия лицензии на содержимое.

**Вопросы:**

1. Что делать, если я вижу плагиат?

   Например, автор ответа скопировал содержимое под лицензией CC-BY-SA (это весь Stack Exchange и почти вся Википедия, но не дал ссылку на источник и не упомянул автора.

**В частности:**

2. Что делать, если с помощью правки можно выполнить условия лицензии?
3. Что делать, если невозможно с помощью правки выполнить условия лицензии (например, содержимое является проприетарным кодом)?
4. Что делать, если лицензия на содержимое неизвестна? Можно ли оставить содержимое, подразумевая «добросовестное использование»?
5. Как стимулировать пользователей соблюдать лицензии на содержимое?

---

Ответ, который спровоцировал это обсуждение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443334/181472

Пожалуйста, **не ставьте там минусы**, чтобы «наказать» автора. Ответ достаточно хороший.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как мне кажется, сообщество Stack Overflow на русском - это неотъемлемая часть современного цивилизованного Интернета, в котором существуют как строгие юридические законы, так и негласные правила хорошего тона. В большинстве случаев нормами установлено, что следует по возможности (или необходимости) указывать авторство содержимого, исходной идеи и т. д. Таким образом, если вы видите, что содержимое сообщения полностью заимствовано, пожалуйста, попросите у автора добавить ссылку на оригинал и/или его мысли по теме.

Вспомните, например, если алгоритм придумал кто-то из наших коллег, при его обсуждении, мы, в основном, ссылаемся на автора, даже если контекст разговора этого не требует. Мы поступаем так из норм морали. Не думаю, что общаясь в Интернете мы должны пренебрегать ими.

Сайт открыт для любых знаний относящихся к тематике сообщества, но в случае возникновения каких-либо споров, скорее всего, администрация не будет вступать в перепал с правообладателями, а просто удалит конфликтные сообщения - Stack Overflow на русском создан с целью обмена, накопления и классификации знаний, а не разбирательств.

Answer (score -4):

Ничего не делать. Информация должна быть **свободной**.

Comment: Свободной как free beer или free speech? Или как фильм на пиратском трекере? Не будем же мы устраивать здесь PirateOverflow и всем назло нарушать даже CC-BY-SA, которая не создает какой-то большой, непреодолимой несвободы и легко выполняется.

Comment: Лично я считаю, что каждый должен поступать так, считает правильным. Хотите навязать всем свои правила? Весьма вероятно, что это и получится, а вот отделенные последствия могут оказаться вовсе и не теми, каких вы желали.