# Можно ли задавать технические вопросы с юридической или финансовой составляющей

Tags: поддержка, тематика

У меня есть вопрос о возможности легального использования одной технологии в фирме, в которой я работаю. Но боюсь получить минусы, если задам этот вопрос на ruSO. Поэтому сначала решил спросить, можно ли задавать такие вопросы.

Чтобы было понятнее, уточню, в чем вопрос заключается.

> Есть платная технология (скажем, АБВГ), но у ее производителя нет представительства в России, поэтому накладную подписать некому, а по другому у нас не делается. Так же в новой версии Visual Studio 2015 вышла бесплатная версия, в которую включена эта технология, но не понятно, обозначает ли это, что использование АБВГ стало бесплатным (что вряд ли) или нет..? И вообще, есть ли варианты легального использования этой технологии в сложившихся условиях, при том, что из своего кармана карточкой я платить не готов?

То есть, вопрос не совсем технический, а в какой-то степени юридический или финансовый... Можно ли такие задавать?

Comment: Что же это за технология такая если её еще не форкнули красноглазые или не сделали таблетку и не выкинули на раздачу в BitTorrent? Видать не нужна никому.

Comment: @igumnov для юрлиц версия с торрентов не годится.

Comment: это вопрос про LightSwitch?

Comment: Сдается мне что это несчастное юрлицо за 5 минут вылетит в трубу вместе со всем своими сотрудниками если будет бездумно тратить по 15000 долларов за одну копию IDE, когда рядом бесплатно валяется какой-нибудь Vim или Emacs.

Comment: @igumnov у MS есть всякие там bizspark, которые дают и ide, и кредиты на azure нахаляву. и, кстати, именно из-за "возьмите vim или emacs" эти вопросы скатываются в оффтоп. Под .net в vim разрабатывать, мягко говоря, медленно и неудобно.

Comment: @Andrey Komissarov я не считаю, что вопрос только про лицензирование - онтопик. можете попробовать его задать, если заминусуют - удалить. но вообще у MS сами по себе технологии бесплатны, лицензированию подлежат только инструменты разработки. Т.е. если вы написали что-то c помощью бесплатной студии - то никакая особая лицензия для запуска этого "чего-то" на другой машине не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!! Задам в ruSO...

Comment: @igumnov: что за IDE такая за $15000?

Comment: @Nick UntitledSuperMegaEvilPropietaryIDE2015, с инновационной функцией Search and Replace в меню и оригинальной зеленой кнопочкой Run прямо на панели инструментов для запуска программы конечно же.

Comment: @igumnov а еще в ней хороший отладчик всего подряд :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У нас есть такой вопрос: [Как оформить "свободную лицензию" на исходный код ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/87172/181472)

Он на сайте в данный момент 12й по количеству голосов. Я это понимаю так, что тема лицензирования ПО всё-таки важна и интересна (даже несмотря на то, что обычный участник SO не является юристом, специализирующимся на лицензировании).

К соблюдению лицензий на чужое ПО у нас в русскоговорящих странах традиционно [пофигистический/бунтарский подход](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1077/181472). Даже здесь в комментариях намекается на торренты. Однако, для юрлиц и крупных проектов такой подход не годится.

Украсть нельзя, можно только выбрать между различными платными и бесплатными решениями. В некоторых случаях хорошие платные инструменты или компоненты могут решать технические задачи гораздо лучше бесплатных и открытых. (Например, VS+ReSharper, на мой взгяд, лучше подходит для разработки под .net, чем Vim).  Можно считать выбор и решение о покупке частью проектирования архитектуры проекта. Было бы полезно хотя бы понимать, каковы экономические факторы и как их учитывать.

Так что я думаю, что при выполнении прочих условий такие вопросы задавать можно. Прочие условия — это те же, что и для всех остальных вопросов: возможность ответить достаточно кратко и объективно, а также полезность для остальных участников.

В данном случае вопрос, насколько я понимаю, вполне конкретный: «Если моя IDE имеет поддержку и шаблоны для проектов по технологии X, значит ли это, что я имею право использовать эту технологию без ограничений, или нужно дополнительно приобретать лицензию?»

Судя по [комментарию PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9#comment3419_1234), объективный ответ возможен.